# What does plus '+' operator mean between two propositions in Coq

Tags: coq

I am struggling with the plus operator between two propositions (maybe types) in Coq. I already could figure out this is something like "or" (maybe "xor") and I think it says that something is decidable but I cannot understand the complete meaning of it, and where does this sign come from (in classical mathematics).

P. S. Of course I already googled and researched but couldn't find the complete sophisticated answer I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [`sum`](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#sum) datatype, where `A + B` is basically `A` or `B`. The main difference with `A \/ B` is that it lives in `Type`, so it has computational content. That is to say, given `A \/ B` you cannot produce a boolean such that `if A then true else false`.

Another way to see it is that for `A B : Prop`, `A + B -> A \/ B` holds, but not the converse.

`Prop` is a special, impredicative sort in Coq; I recommend reading the manual about it.